# WPF DataGrid select row with value from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, textbox

In my application I want to select row in dataGrid1 that, in column "Order", have value actually stored in textBox.
How can I select row programmaticaly (there won't be two rows with same number)?

Comment: Update your answer to include your code and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Name your DataGrid so that the code in the code behind can access it. In the textbox subscribe to the `KeyUp` or `LostFocus` events and find the object which matches what was put in the textbox.

**Example List Contains Orders with a unique OrderId**

[image]

**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          Name="myGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"/>

<TextBox x:Name="tbSelection"
         KeyUp="tbSelection_LostFocus"/>
```

**Codebehind**

```
private void tbSelection_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbSelection.Text) == false)
    {
        int userOrderId; 

        if (int.TryParse(tbSelection.Text, out userOrderId))
        {
            var orders = myGrid.ItemsSource as List<Order>;

            var order = orders.FirstOrDefault(ord => ord.OrderId == userOrderId);

            if (order != null)
                myGrid.SelectedItem = order;
            else
                myGrid.SelectedIndex = -1; // Default to nothing.

        }
        else
            myGrid.SelectedIndex = -1; // Default to nothing.
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]